# How to attach new JFrame to an already made frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

How do I connect a frame to an existing frame?

The code below is the code for the appletframe.  What I want to do is add the other code which is for the frame to be connected to the bottom of the AppletFrame, so that when I drag the Appletframe the frame code with we dragged with it as well. Basically I want the frame code to be attached with the appletFrame so that both the frames are together.

### AppletFrame

```
    appletFrame = new JFrame(Settings.serverName);
            Loader.webclient = false;
            appletFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            appletFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
            appletPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            appletFrame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/icon.png")));
            appletPanel.add(this);
            appletPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(767, 537));
            appletFrame.getContentPane().add(appletPanel, "Center");
            appletFrame.pack();
            appletFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            appletFrame.setVisible(true);
    JMenuBar jmenubar = new JMenuBar();
            appletFrame.setJMenuBar(jmenubar);
            Layout = new FlowLayout();
            ImageIcon keyboard = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/keyboard.png")));
            ImageIcon wrench = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/wrench.png")));
            Button1 = new JButton("Vote");
            Button2 = new JButton("Item List");
            Button3 = new JButton("Screenshot");
            Button4 = new JButton(wrench);
            Button5 = new JButton(keyboard);
            Button4.setBorder(null);
            Button4.setBorderPainted(false);
            Button4.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            Button5.setBorder(null);
            Button5.setBorderPainted(false);
            Button5.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            jmenubar.setLayout(Layout);
            jmenubar.add(Button1);
            jmenubar.add(Button2);
            jmenubar.add(Button3);
            jmenubar.add(Button4);
            jmenubar.add(Button5);
            Button1.addActionListener(this);
            Button2.addActionListener(this);
            Button3.addActionListener(this);
            Button4.addActionListener(this);
            Button5.addActionListener(this);
            Button1.setText("Vote");
            Button2.setText("Item List");
            Button3.setText("Screenshot");
```

Frame which I want it to be attached with the AppletFrame. I want this to be attached to the bottom of the appletFrame, but I don't know how to do it.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
        frame.setSize(775,121); 
        frame.setResizable(false); 
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("TEST"); 
        textArea.setSize(400,400);          
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);     
        textArea.setEditable(false);    
        textArea.setVisible(true);     
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (textArea);    
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy   (JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);          
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);     
        frame.add(scroll);    
        frame.setVisible(true);     
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Use a [`JSplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html) instead.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Attributes `Loader`, `Layout` & `Button1` should be named `loader`, `layout` & `button1`..  Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I alluded to in my first comment, this GUI would be better combined into a single top-level container.

Here is an SSCCE<sup>1</sup> (mentioned in my 2nd comment) that shows the basic idea, though now I have a better idea of the effect required, the `JSplitPane` seems less appropriate.   Here I just combine the GUI elements into the same layout.

[image: TestGUI]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class TestGUI extends JPanel {

    TestGUI() {
        JFrame appletFrame = new JFrame("Settings.serverName");
        appletFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        appletFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

        JPanel appletPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        appletPanel.add(this);
        appletPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(767, 537));
        appletFrame.getContentPane().add(appletPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Don't use a menu-bar as a tool-bar!
        JToolBar jmenubar = new JToolBar();
        appletPanel.add(jmenubar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        JButton Button1 = new JButton("Vote");
        JButton Button2 = new JButton("Item List");
        JButton Button3 = new JButton("Screenshot");
        JButton Button4 = new JButton("wrench");
        JButton Button5 = new JButton("keyboard");
        Button4.setBorder(null);
        Button4.setBorderPainted(false);
        Button4.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        Button5.setBorder(null);
        Button5.setBorderPainted(false);
        Button5.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jmenubar.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jmenubar.add(Button1);
        jmenubar.add(Button2);
        jmenubar.add(Button3);
        jmenubar.add(Button4);
        jmenubar.add(Button5);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("TEST", 4, 65 );
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setVisible(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (
            textArea,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        appletPanel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        appletFrame.pack();
        appletFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        appletFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

1. And yes, this would have arrived sooner if I'd had an SSCCE to start with. ;)